# How to convert this code from ActionScript 2.0 to ActionScript 3.0?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I make a kind of simple game for assessing students, I can build the code based ActionScript 2.0. I hear from a fried that ActionScript 3.0 can be used on Android. So I hope my game can play in Android,
this is my ActionScript 2.0 code

```js
stop();
score=0;//skor total
step=1;//gerakan pemain
moveframe=4;
number=0;//dadu

a1.onPress=function(){
    number=0;
    number=number+1;
    score=score+1;
    step=step+1;
    moveframe=moveframe+1;
    _root.player._x = _root["square"+step]._x;
    _root.player._y = _root["square"+step]._y;
    _root.gotoAndStop(moveframe);
    _root.soal.gotoAndStop(step);
    trace(step);
}
b1.onPress=function(){
    number=0;
    number=number+1;
    score=score+1;
    step=step+1;
    moveframe=moveframe+1;
    _root.player._x = _root["square"+step]._x;
    _root.player._y = _root["square"+step]._y;
    _root.gotoAndStop(moveframe);
    _root.soal.gotoAndStop(step);
    trace(step);
}
c1.onPress=function(){
    number=0;
    number=number+1;
    score=score+1;
    step=step+1;
    moveframe=moveframe+1;
    _root.player._x = _root["square"+step]._x;
    _root.player._y = _root["square"+step]._y;
    _root.gotoAndStop(moveframe);
    _root.soal.gotoAndStop(step);
    trace(step);
}
d1.onPress=function(){
    number=0;
    number=number+1;
    score=score+1;
    step=step+1;
    moveframe=moveframe+1;
    _root.player._x = _root["square"+step]._x;
    _root.player._y = _root["square"+step]._y;
    _root.gotoAndStop(moveframe);
    _root.soal.gotoAndStop(step);
    trace(step);
}
e1.onPress=function(){
    number=0;
    number=number+1;
    score=score+1;
    step=step+1;
    moveframe=moveframe+1;
    _root.player._x = _root["square"+step]._x;
    _root.player._y = _root["square"+step]._y;
    _root.gotoAndStop(moveframe);
    _root.soal.gotoAndStop(step);
    trace(step);
}
```

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Rewrite by hand. As far as I know there is no other option

Comment: I stuck on how to write ["square"+step], should (step) converted to string?

Comment: Have you tried `String(step)`? Does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AS3 that would be something like that:

```
stop();

var score:int = 0;//skor total
var step:int = 1;//gerakan pemain
var moveframe:int = 4;
// this one is useless: number=0;//dadu

for each (var aButton:InteractiveObject in [a1,b1,c1,d1,e1])
{
    aButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onButton);
}

function onButton(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    step++;
    score++;
    moveframe++;

    root.player.x = root.getChildByName("square"+step).x;
    root.player.y = root.getChildByName("square"+step).y;

    root.gotoAndStop(moveframe);
    root.soal.gotoAndStop(step);

    trace(step);
}
```

Keep in mind that you need do much more than just that if you want to have your app running on Android smoothly. Yet if you're doing it just for your own fun, then yes, just migrating to AS3 will suffice.